# correct parsing in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Sorry for my english. I dont know i correct parsing or not. I have json string

```
    {
        "TypeCar": {
            "1": {
                "type": "1",
                "id": "1"
            },
            "2": {
                "type": "1",
                "id": "2"
            }

            .
            .
            .

            "55": {
                "type": "1",
                "id": "55"
            }
        }
```

Ok, its simple i get json string and in cycle I will do everything like this

```
JSONObject typeCar = jsonObject.getJSONObject("TypeCar");
for(int j = 1; j < typeCar.length(); j++) {
 JSONObject numberTcar = typeCar.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(j));

 String type = numberTcar.getString("type");
 String id = numberTcar.getString("id");
}
```

But if i have json somthing like this

```
{
            "TypeCar": {
                "10": {
                    "type": "1",
                    "id": "10"
                },
                "4": {
                    "type": "1",
                    "id": "4"
                }

                 "14": {
                    "type": "1",
                    "id": "14"
                }
            }
```

as I then parse it?

**UPD:**

parse iterator:

```
//my all json string
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());
//json only TypeCar
JSONObject sensorTypes = jsonObject.getJSONObject("TypeCar");

Iterator<String> iterator = sensorTypes.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String currentKey = iterator.next();
    JSONObject obj = jsonObject.optJSONObject(currentKey);

    if(obj != null) {

       //its now work, what i do wrong?
       String type = obj.getString("type");
       String id = obj.getString("id");

}
}
```

Comment: it's the third time, you post the same question

Comment: @Blackbelt i have not currect answer

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm trying to learn as much as I'd better parse when in `TypeCar` number may change. Use iterator or what?

Comment: yes, you have to use the iterator. If it is not working, please ask for clarification in the original post, instead of spamming over and over the same question

Comment: @Blackbelt please see my qestions i update it. What i do wrong?

Comment: you have to use `sensorTypes.optJSONObject(currentKey);`